# how to make a handle of a bottle like this one?

Tags: modeling, vertices

i'm new to modeling

and....

**picture 1 is the one i want to make..**

**and i made something like picture 2**

**but i couldn't handle the handle**

**and what i did just don't look the part (picture 4)**

please help!

(they dont let me post more than 2 pic so i made a long pic in PS)

this is my .blender file 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9ngqlsbk2selv1/BOTTLE.blend?dl=0

about how i made this , i made it with a box,with a subsurf modifier ,and extrude many many times.

and i apply the subsurf modifier before using Boolean modifier to cut a hole.(because if i dont apply strange things will happen)

and there is a bottle before apply subsuft modifier in my scene.
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend watching the 'blender beginner' tutorial series from Blender Guru. Andrew explains the modeling basics quite well and it should definitely help you out.
 note: You are using way to much subdivisions in your model. So this would be the first thing you should reconsider when building the topology.

Comment: thank you Delagone , i'll definiate check on that tutorial series!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use Mesh Modeling with Subdivision Surfaces**

[image]

Hi Jason,
The mesh in your file is very high poly, which often makes it more difficult to edit. Next time, try using poly mesh modeling with a subdivision surface modifier.

Try capturing the shape with as few polygons as possible, and let the modifier help give the appearance of a smoother surface.It's usually easier to edit when there's less geometry to work with, and the modifier will still give the benefit of appearing more detailed than the base mesh actually is.

You can add extra edge loop cuts to sharpen areas, and you can increase and decrease the view count in the subdivision surface modifier. You can even crease your mesh in the N Properties panel under the transform section. Have a look at the image and the blend file provided.

If you often model these kinds of objects, consider taking a look at Claas Kuhnen's youtube videos. He often does product design and concept modeling tutorials that you may find useful.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/user/cekuhnen

Hope this helps,
Good Luck!

Comment: You're welcome! Good Luck!

Comment: hi , i have a question , at first you start with a plane , and extrude egeds multi times to capture the basic shape of the bottle, right?  and how do you cut a hole in that mesh, and where did the ellipse come from?

Comment: i got it , move vertices to caputure that ellipse shape ,then extrude and scale that shape, and with subsurf modifier , it automaticly become a ellipse.

Comment: Good Job Jason :)