# Complex bend insets on a plastic bottle

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Any idea how to make these insets on a plastic bottle? Tried with bezier + lettice but results are not good and with no control once applied.

thanks!
[image]
[image: bottle]

Comment: You might try a displacement map (with uv mapping) using a texture you draw. Notice that you will have to draw the falloffs of your texture so that the insets will be smooth.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75692/creating-curve-design/75697#75697  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112563/weird-artifact-in-blender-render https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/making-rounded-dips-in-cylinder/55762#55762 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70537/how-to-make-a-handle-of-a-bottle-like-this-one